# What order would a Taylor Young polynomial be when $f(n)=\ln(1+\frac{n}{a^n})$?

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

Suppose I want to calculate the Taylor-Young polynomial of a function $f(n)=\ln(1+\frac{n}{a^n})$ with $a>1$ to the order two. What bothers me is that I am unsure what should I put in the $o(?)$ part.

I would get something like, at point $0$:

$$f(n)= \frac{n}{a^n} - \frac{n^2}{2a^{2n}} + o(n^2)$$

But I am sure unsure if this is right. Is the $o(n^2)$ correct?

Comment: Does $x$ mean $n$?

Comment: Yes, I made the appropriate edit to prevent this confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $\log(1+x)= x-\frac{x^2}{2} + o(x^2)$. Then, for $x=\frac{n}{a^n}$ you get: $$\log\bigg(1+\frac{n}{a^n}\bigg)=\frac{n}{a^n}-\frac{n^2}{2a^{2n}} + o\bigg(\frac{n^2}{a^{2n}}\bigg)$$

EDIT: as Alex M. pointed out, for $n \to 0$ we have $a^{2n} \to 1$. So $o(\frac{n^2}{a^{2n}}) = o(n^2)$

Comment: ...And since $n$ is close to $0$, we have $a^n$ close to $1$, so $o \left( \frac {n^2} {a^{2n}} \right) = o(n^2)$, so the OP is correct.

Comment: True, I thought we were considering $n \to +\infty$ ($n/a^n \to 0$) for some reason. Probably the $a>1$ misled me, since I see no reason why that should be specified for $n$ close to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You state you are looking for a polynomial, but you are going in a direction where you have an expression that is not polynomial in $n$. To just compute the Taylor polynomial directly:

If $$f(x)=\ln(1+x/a^x)$$ then 
$$f'(x)=\frac{1}{1+x/a^x}\frac{1-x\ln(a)}{a^{x}}$$
and 
$$f''(x)=\frac{1}{1+x/a^x}\frac{-2\ln(a)+x\ln(a)^2}{a^{x}}-\frac{1}{\left(1+x/a^x\right)^2}\left(\frac{1-x\ln(a)}{a^{x}}\right)^2$$

So $f(0)=0$, $f'(0)=1$, and $f''(0)=-2\ln(a)-1$, and $$f(x)=x-\frac{2\ln(a)+1}{2}x^2+\operatorname{o}(x^3)$$